# Is the data parameter for pandas.DataFrame lazily evaluated?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

Re:

> class pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None,
>   dtype=None, copy=False)[source]

And:

> classmethod DataFrame.from_records(data, index=None, exclude=None,
>   columns=None, coerce_float=False, nrows=None)[source]

Is the data parameter evaluated lazily?  e.g. if I call it with a data parameter that is a generator, will it totally consume the generator or only read it when required.

e.g. Suppose I have this snippet:

```
import csv
csvinput = (row["line"] for index, row in InputDataSet.iterrows())
rdr = csv.reader(csvinput)
OutputDataSet = pandas.DataFrame().from_records(rdr)
```

(Note that it's not reading CSV data per se that I'm asking about.  Granted there are probably other, better ways to do that).

Where InputDataSet is another DataFrame.  The code works fine, but might have scalability problems if the row sets are eagerly evaluated.  Imagine that InputDataSet is retrieving rows in csv format from some source -- perhaps a file or web site or who knows what.  Ideally (for me, that is), the iterrows() call on the InputDataSet dataframe would be lazily evaluated -- that is one row at a time as needed.  Similarly for the OutpuDataSet.  It would be great if the from_records method was lazy.  Then I could have another section lazily reading the OutputDataSet.

This question came about while playing with Python support in SQL Server 2017.  For large row sets, eager evaluation will be a problem for this sort of code.

just did a dead-easy test:

```
>>> g = ((x, x+1) for x in range(5))
>>> d = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(g)
>>> next(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

So, that says to me that the from_records method is eager, which is disappointing.

Comment: answered my own question

Answer (score 0):

See testcase in original post.  the methods are eager